# NestJS: How to pass the error from one Error Filter to another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am using NestJS for my application and catch all the errors in a Filter.
I have some logic where I want every specific error to be formatted and then be sent to the final `ExceptionFilter`. I have the following code:

```
@Catch()
    export class GlobalErrorFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
 public catch(error: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
// do something
}
    }
```

And also this one:

```
@Catch(NotFoundException)
export class NotfoundFilter implements ExceptionFilter<NotFoundException> {
    public catch(error: NotFoundException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Is there a way that the first Filter catches the error after the first one? Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If multiple filters would match to an error, the one with the highest priority will run. There are two factors for the priority of an [`ExceptionFilter`](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters):

### Global vs. Local

Filters that are bound to a controller or one of its methods always have higher priority than global filters.

Controller:

```
// First NotfoundFilter is checked
@UseFilters(NotfoundFilter)
```

Global:

```
// Then GlobalErrorFilter is checked
app.useGlobalFilters(new GlobalErrorFilter());
```

### Registration Order

The filter that is registered last will have the highest priority. So the most specific filter should be registered last:

```
@UseFilters(GlobalErrorFilter, NotfoundFilter)
//          ^^^ 2nd            ^^^ 1st
```

or

```
app.useGlobalFilters(new GlobalErrorFilter(), new NotfoundFilter());
//                       ^^^ 2nd                  ^^^ 1st
```

Comment: I couldn't find this in the official documentation, thanks. Do you know where is this behaviour defined?

Comment: @IanSebastian I am afraid I do not remember, sorry. It definitely is not in the docs, I either just tried it out or looked at the source code.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 different exceptions here with a specific type. So it should be possible (i think) that after the first filter catches the exception you could have it do something and then throw a new exception of the other type which should then be caught there. Hope it helps

Comment: I tried to do that, i.e. throw a new exception from the second Filter. It doesn't work, only one of two filters is triggered.

Comment: That's a good idea but you must never throw an exception from an `ExceptionFilter`. You can try it, this will cause an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`. The `ExceptionFilter` is the last place where an error hits and always has to handle it by setting the response correspondingly. Also, only *one* `ExceptionFilter` handles an error. If you have multiple ones that match then the first match according to the priorities explained in my post will be used.

Answer (score 0):

personally I using on every child catch error `return Promise.reject(error)`, by aware that this has to be used inside async fcn only!